# hsqldb simulate deadlock or timeout

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, deadlock, hsqldb

I am using hsqldb in combination with Hibernate and Spring and I randomly see a `org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException`.

I am trying to reproduce this issue in a controlled way.
So far I have found some information about using the `LOCK` command. So I have tried the following:

```
lock table myTable WRITE;
```

but I don't get the result I expect.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: I expect to get a LockAcquisitionException when I try to execute another statement that should write into myTable which was locked for write.

Comment: The lock is released at commit. If you are using MVCC, the LOCK TABLE statement does not work at all.